ingress-nginx web page return a 304 Not Modified
I am practicing docker and k8s using Windows and i got a big problem that i actually don't know how to solve, my web page is just a simple react page, and i push it to docker hub and use k8s to run it, to do the networking, i use ingress-nginx, when i run minikube tunnel command and run localhost in the browser, the page appear for a second, then it disappear immediately after that, leaving a complete empty white page, when i check the network, it show that the route return a 304 Not Modified, so i look for solution, and come with the solution below:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";

But right after i apply it, i got an error:
for: "k8s\\ingress-service.yml": error when patching "k8s\\ingress-service.yml": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet annotation cannot be used. Snippet directives are disabled by the Ingress administrator

Turnout that Snippet directives are disabled by default, i look for a way to enable it, but nothing help, a few solution just simple state like "you have to set allowSnippetAnnotations=true", ... or somethings similar with no actual instruction how to to it, i have found a few ways, like run the command:
kubectl edit configmap -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller

and add:
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: “true”

Then reset the controller, but i didn't work, i also delete ingress-nginx, then copy the source code that need to be applied in a file, then modified the allow-snippet-annotations to true and applied it, but also didn't work.
So i completely stuck at this point because i really don't know how to enable allow-snippet-annotations to fix 304 Not Modified issue, if you know how to fix it, please show me :(
Here is my ingress file:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations: 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      add_header "Cache-Control max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: server-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 5000


Can you please update the ingress controller to one of the latest versions and try to set the annotations again.You can refer to the github link for more details. Also, please note that quotations started from Cache-control instead of max-age under configuration-snippet in the ingress file you shared.

how can i update it? i follow the document and pull ingress-nginx from here:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

Verify that the allow-snippet-annotation is present in the Ingress resource or not. You can check this by using the command kubectl get ingress ingress-service -o yaml . If it is not present, your config map edit is not done properly and the annotation is not added or saved. You need to apply the changes by using the command kubectl apply -f ingress-service.yml and then you need to restart the ingress controller by using the command kubectl rollout restart deployment -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller.

Once the Ingress Controller has restarted, if the issue persists, sometimes you need to re-apply your Ingress resource, which may help to resolve your issue and also refer to the similar SO link for more details.

Based on the error message, the Ingress administrator has disabled snippet directives. You can request the Ingress admin to enable the same. As an alternative, try using the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size annotation to set the maximum request body size instead of nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet annotation.
